# Azure function app, collect application docker logs

Tags: azure, logging, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-app-service-plans

I have Function App which deployed as a docker container on Linux App Service plan(NodeJS). I can see stream logs of my function, but I want to store it somewhere else except function filesystem. Is it possible or not?

I configured App Service logs feature to store application docker logs in my function filesystem itself. But, maybe I can somehow store it on Azure BLOB or somewhere else in Azure?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**I have deployed dockerized function to Azure function app:**

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

**Check if below steps helps to check your function logs:**

1. **Application Insights:**

- Make sure **Application Insights** is enabled for your **function app**.

[image]

- To see function logs, go to Application Insights of `functionapp=>Logs` and run the query `traces`:

[image]

2. **Log Stream:**

You can check the function logs in **LogStream** after enabling the `App Service Logs=>Application Logs=>File System`:

**App Insights Logs:**

[image]

**FileSystem Logs:**

[image]

3. **Configure Log Analytics Workspace to check the logs:**

Go to `Function App=> Diagonstic settings`=> configure diagnostic settings as shown below to send the logs to storage account:

[image]

- Run the **functionapp**, you will be able to see the **log file** in the storage account as shown below:

[image]

Open the folder and download the file, you can see the function logs stored in that file:

[image]

4. **KUDU site:**

You can also find the **docker logs** in **KUDU site** of **function app** (Function App=> Advanced Tools=> click on Go), click on **Docker logs-Dowload as zip**:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, I researched all this methods, but the main problem is my Function App can't send the logs to Analytics Workspace. Also, I don't understand why I need implement applicationinsight NodeJS library to be able to send App logs, why I can't just use console.log() console.info()

Comment: Did you configure your function app to send logs to analytics workspace? If yes, are you getting any error?

Comment: I configured my app to send logs to analytics workspace , but I can’t see FunctionAppLogs table with my logs. I am using vanilla NodeJS without Microsoft libraries for this services maybe it’s the main problem?

Comment: Also, I rechecked that my Function App hasn't any functions (as on your first screenshot HttpExample), I am using simple NodeJS app, which triggers by API management via FunctionApp URL, but still no logs appear in LogAnalytics, especially stdout (console.log, console.info). Thank you!